# Rowkey.ToLower() while querying on Azure table throws Exception

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Querying for an specific entity having e.RowKey.ToLower() throws an exception

```
CustomerEntity customerEntity = (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<CustomerEntity>("Customer")
                                     where e.RowKey.ToLower() == firstName.ToLower()                                         
                                     select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

Basically i want to check for case insensitive username..Azure table is managed by our partner so i can not instruct them to enter the User entry into table in lower case.

I need to handle this in code.

REgards,
Vivek

Answer (score 3):

ToLower() isn't valid as part of the filter expression because Table Storage doesn't support that as an operation.

You have two options:

1. Ensure that all the data you put in is lower-case. If you also need the upper/mixed case version, put it in another column.
2. Pull back all the data and do the filter in memory. This is valid if you've only got a small number of records.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an exception because the `ToLower()` method is not a supported method in Azure.

I think you could do the comparison this way instead

```
where e.RowKey.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

It should accomplish what you're trying to do, but it uses the supported `Equals()` method instead.

Comment: Hi Evan,Thanks for your response..Using Equals is returning null eventhough record exists with specified username..no luck

Comment: How are you verifying the record exists? Are you sure that the username is the entire rowkey?

Comment: Yeah property.Equals still doesn't work in Azure.Data.Tables 12.8.0.0, it's like the condition isn't met.